# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el valor del índice de una lista o de un diccionario?

Tags: python

Trato de hacer que al iterar una cantidad de veces se almacenen los valores de unas variables definidas en una lista y en un diccionario de dos códigos diferentes pero similares.

En el primer código quiero que los valores de la lista me imprima de forma estética `El valor de Columnas es 3`, pero al imprimir me arroja esto: `El valor de ['Columnas', 3] es 3`

```
elementos = [['Columnas'], ['Trabes'], ['Losas']]

almacenador = []
keys = [key for key in elementos]

for cosa in range(len(elementos)):
    elementos[cosa].append(int(input(f'Escribe el valor de {elementos[cosa][0]}: ')))
    almacenador.append(elementos[cosa])
print(f'\nEl valor de {keys[0]} es {almacenador[0][1]}')
print('\n')
```

En el segundo código quiero que la lista me imprima exactamente lo mismo que en la lista anterior, pero al imprimir me ocurre justo lo contrario: `El valor de ['Piedra'] es [9]`, yo quiero que me imprima `El valor de Piedra es 9`

```
numeros = {'Piedra': [], 'Pato': [], 'Coco': []}
clave = [key for key in numeros]
almacenado=[]
for datos in numeros:
    numeros[datos].append(int(input(f'Ingrese el valor de sus {numeros[datos]}: ')))
    almacenado.append(numeros[datos])
    print(f'\nEl valor de {clave[0]} es {numeros[0]}')
```

Probé muchos métodos, con índices, con claves, con keys, con items, etc., pero no he conseguido que me arroje lo que busco. Me pueden ayudar con este problema. Les agradezco mucho su tiempo por leerme y apoyarme. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta al hacer el for pues prácticamente copias lo de la lista, debe ser:

```
keys = [key[0] for key in elementos]
```

Y para los diccionarios , no hace falta iterar sobre sus elementos.

```
numeros = {'Piedra': [], 'Pato': [], 'Coco': []}
#clave = [key for key in numeros]
almacenado=[]
for datos in numeros:
    numeros[datos].append(int(input(f'Ingrese el valor de sus {datos}: ')))
    almacenado.append(numeros[datos])
    print(f'\nEl valor de {datos} es {numeros[datos][0]}')
```

Si no vas a almacenar varios valores puedes reemplazar la lista por un valor como 0 y en vez de usar append solo lo iguales al valor, de esta forma.

```
numeros = {'Piedra': 0, 'Pato': 0, 'Coco': 0}
almacenado=[]
for datos in numeros:
    numeros[datos] = int(input(f'Ingrese el valor de sus {datos}: '))
    almacenado.append(numeros[datos])
    print(f'\nEl valor de {datos} es {numeros[datos]}')
```

Para obtener o imprimir todos los valores, haces uso de un ciclo for y de la funcion `items()` lo que nos devuelve una tupla `(clave, valor)`.

**Para diccionarios**

```
for dato, valor in numeros.items():
     print(f'El valor de {dato} es {valor}')
```

**Para listas**

```
for dato,valor in elementos:
     print(f'El valor de {dato} es {valor}')
```

Comment: Si quisiera que me arrojara al final del ciclo las tres variables, ¿cómo lo haría?, es un problema que tenía desde el inicio. Por ejemplo al concluir el ciclo for me imprima: `El valor de Columna es 1`, `El valor de Trabe es 2`, `El valor de Losa es 3`, me gustaría que se imprimiera después, no durante. No entiendo cómo llamar de forma secuencial a los elementos de la lista para concatenarlos con los resultados

Comment: listo edite la respuesta agregando eso

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo voy a estudiar para aprendérmelo, en este momento estoy optimizando mucho la forma de escribir el código para evitar la redundancia. Saludos!

Comment: no te preocupes poco a poco iras avanzando y aqui esta la comunidad de SO si requieres de ayuda.

Comment: hay alguna forma de mandarte un pm para preguntarte algo acerca de python?

Comment: si tienes una pregunta, es mejor que la hagas en este sitio, asi aportas a la comunidad

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124156/discussion-between-christian-and-ulises-antonio-chavez).

Comment: Muchas gracias, en el debate del chat ya hice un comentario